# Canonical divisor of $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to compute the canonical divisor of $\mathbb C^n,\; \mathbb B^n=\{z\in \mathbb C^n|\; |z|<1\}$? i.e $K_{\mathbb C^n}$ and $K_{\mathbb B^n}$

Comment: If you consider $\mathbb{C}^n$ as an affine scheme, then the canonical sheaf is isomorphic to the structure sheaf as it is a regular scheme. I do not know how to define your $B^n$, algebraically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{B}^n$ every line bundle is trivial or, equivalently every divisor is principal. In particular, canonical divisors are trivial.